# array to get object's value failed in php

Tags: php, xml

why is this wrong?

```
[enclosure] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [url] => http://www.thestar.com.my/~/media/Images/TSOL/Photos-Gallery/features/2014/07/02/dominiclau020714.ashx?crop=1&w=460&h=345&
                    [length] => 
                    [type] => image/jpeg
                )

        )
```

I want to get the url to get the image file

I wrote `print_r($eachItem->enclosure['@attributes']->url)` it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: What if you tried `$eachItem->enclosure->{'@attributes'}['url']` or `$eachItem->enclosure->['@attributes']['url']` as `@attributes` is an `Array` not an object?

Comment: the proper way of getting the attributes is by using the `->attributes()` method

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct way of getting the attribute value. Use [**`->attributes()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method:

```
echo (string) $eachItem->enclosure->attributes()['url'];
// as of PHP 5.4 (dereferencing)
```

Or

```
// PHP 5.3 below
$eachItem_attribute = $eachItem->enclosure->attributes();
echo (string) $eachItem_attribute['url'];
```

Comment: +1 This is what you should be doing OP, I overlooked the SimpleXML.

Comment: it became this SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => http://www.thestar.com.my/~/media/Images/TSOL/Photos-Gallery/features/2014/07/02/JamyYangMingjie020714.ashx?crop=1&w=460&h=345&
)

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => http://www.thestar.com.my/~/media/Images/TSOL/Photos-Gallery/features/2014/07/02/dominiclau020714.ashx?crop=1&w=460&h=345&
)

Comment: @user3522729 add a typecast string `(string)`, check the revision

Comment: Or, use the array dereference on `->enclosure` itself.

Comment: @Jack yeah probably use that one, the OP didn't post the whole structure so that it'l be easier to analyze. you'll see the OP posted a bunch (spawned) new questions regarding this issue. with using other accounts.

Answer (score 0):

#### Right & Quick Format

```
$eachItem->enclosure->attributes()->{'url'};
```